# Show/hide control textbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to Visual Basic and I don't understand what object I need for this task.

I have 5 "control text boxes" that I want to hide show in Powerpoint.  I have the following code and receive a 424 error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox2").Visible = False
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox9").Visible = False
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox8").Visible = False
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox7").Visible = False
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox6").Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox2").Visible = True
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox9").Visible = True
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox8").Visible = True
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox7").Visible = True
  Activesheet.oleobjects("TextBox6").Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: why `activesheet` for `powerpoint-vba`? your question is unclear... add more description of what you have on your presentation(?). You could possibly add some screen shots...

Comment: I mistakenly entered True for all values in this thread, and solved this by removing the "Activesheet.oleobjects()" to state:
    TextBox2.Visible = False
    TextBox2.Visible = True

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint doesn't have worksheets, so there's no Activesheet object.  That'll trigger an error right off the bat.  To simply toggle visibility, you can do this:

```
Sub ToggleVisibility()
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .Shapes("TextBox1").Visible = Not .Shapes("TextBox1").Visible
        .Shapes("TextBox2").Visible = Not .Shapes("TextBox2").Visible
        ' and so on
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I mistakenly entered True for all values in this thread, and solved this by removing the "Activesheet.oleobjects()" to state: TextBox2.Visible = False TextBox2.Visible = True – Michael Schaefer 2 mins ago edit